# Extending custom keyboard's height beyond 216 when using .xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-keyboard-extension

I have a custom keyboard using an interface is laid out in a `.xib` file (which does not use auto-layout). At the moment, I am having trouble extending the **height** of the interface to be more than the default 216 points.

I have attempted to constrain the height of the keyboard by using Apple's suggested method `NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view...`, but it only causes the keyboard to not appear at all.

This is how I initialize the interface in my `KeyboardViewController.m` (a subclass of `InputViewController`)

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomKeyboardLayout" owner:self options:nil];
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width; //these have no effect in determining the height/width of the keyboard
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
self.keyboardOverlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

Comment: Changing the height of your view's frame isn't going to do anything. You have to set the layout constraint of the `UIInputView` attached to your `UIInputViewController` like in the docs, and if there are no views in it that use autoayout, add one that does (as of the last time I was looking into this, it wouldn't work otherwise). If you post what happens when you crash, maybe someone can help you fix it. Also note that you can't go over the size of your inputview, so just setting your `keyboardOverlayView`, assuming that it's not the root view isn't going to have the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @BenPious. Just to make sure I completely understand your suggestion, I should insist on getting the .xib to work with autolayout, so I could then implement the method as recommended by Apple. `keyboardOverlayView` is indeed the root view of the Keyboard view.

Comment: No. You don't have to do that at all. *All* you have to do is have one constraint that resembles the Apple docs on your `UIInputView`, in code. Just set up this constraint, have some invisible subview that has a constraint of some sort to deal with the bugs in Apple's implementation, then add the view that you get from your storyboard as a subview to the `UIInputView`.

Comment: Turning autolayout on in your storyboard is probably not doing anything because you've failed to set any constraints. Also, I haven't confirmed this myself, but it's said that autolayout in keyboards is really slow.

Comment: Thanks for following up and clarifying, @BenPious. You did put me in a good direction: I found that there was an issue with two different constrains conflicting: `Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want...."<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000867c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIInputView:0x7f8ba0c13710(216)]>",
     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618003c8ee70 V:[UIInputView:0x7f8ba0c13710(258)]>"` Hopefully this could help me solve the issue.

Comment: You'll see this output even if you do everything correctly and the height increases. There is no getting around it.